# Java standard annotation for show conflict on using specific argument

Tags: java

A method has some input arguments and possible options are stored in related `enums` for all arguments. But using specific possible option for `argument1`  with a specific option for `argument2` cause conflict. How can I show a warning for other developers to avoid this situation?

**Edit:**

I want to warn others when they want to use those options. For example like when you want to use a deprecated method

Comment: Either write that in the JavaDoc or log a message of both arguments can cause that conflict. Or do both.

Comment: What about applying @Tom's suggestion and throwing IllegalArgumentException on top of that?

Comment: @AlexNikolaenkov I want to warn others when want use those options. For example like when you want to use a deprecated method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have method doSmth(Enum1, Enum2), and enums Enum1 with options A, B, C, and Enum2 with options X, Y, Z, and Enum1.A is incompatible with Enum2.Z, I think it would be more reliable to make 4 enums:

Enum11 {A, B, C}, Enum21 {X, Y},
Enum12 {B, C}, Enum22 {X, Y, Z}

And have two overloaded versions of method doSmth:

doSmth(Enum11, Enum21),
doSmth(Enum12, Enum22).

These can be organized into two subclasses or implementations, e.g. according to Strategy pattern.

Yes, it makes your code more verbose, but also this way the users of your method won't be able to supply incompatible pair of arguments at all. I think it's better than forcing them to sift through documentation in search of cornercases.

Comment: As you noted, this way works but will cause my code be verbose and complex. I prefer to avoid this way.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty common to check parameters (especially parameters of constructors) and throw `IllegalArgumentException` if passed a value or combination that is not allowed.  For example consider this constructor:

```
public DateRange(Date start, Date end) {

}
```

I would add checks like this at a minimum (as well as documenting what is allowed):

```
/**
 * Constructs a new instance.
 *
 * @param start the start date, cannot be null and must be smaller than the end date
 * @param end the end date, cannot be null and must be larger than the start date
 */
public DateRange(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    if (start == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("start cannot be null");
    }
    if (end == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("end cannot be null");
    }
    if (!start.before(end)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("start must be before end");
    }

    this.start = start; 
    this.end = end;
}
```